# Expanding multiple brackets is it 'better' to do them in a particular order?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Just watching [a tutorial](https://www.examsolutions.net/tutorials/expanding-two-brackets/?level=A-Level&board=Edexcel&module=Pure%20Maths%20A-Level&topic=14110) which explained how to expand:

> -2(3a-2)(4a-1)
>   and
>
> (5x - 2)(x - 2)(2x + 1)

In both cases the tutorial recommends to start with solving the rightmost pair first. Obviously (as the tutorial says) there is no mathematical reason to do this,  but are there any rules of thumb/guidelines on which pair to pick for ease of computation?

My instinct is that you should start with the two most complex, and work backwards in terms of complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't really general rules of that kind.

I would tend to do the simplest ones first to keep the arithmetic as simple as possible for as long as possible. And if, like the first example, there are constants there, put them in at the end.

Also look for pairs of the form $(ax+b)(ax-b)=a^2x^2-b^2$ which lose a term from the calculation.

As an example, to compute the product of three successive integers I would write it as $(n-1)n(n+1)=n(n^2-1)=n^3-n$ rather than $n(n+1)(n+2)$. In this way I would use the choice I have to write a simpler form of product.

But others may have different hints.